# HTML in questions but not comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, comments, formatting

Why is it that we can use HTML markup and entities in questions but not in comments? Shouldn't they be the same?

Testing `markdown` here, *italic*, **bold**... well, that seems to work.

Comment: I'd be happy to help with any proposed 'fix' if needed.

Comment: <b>Testing 123</b>

Comment: Hmm... I think `some stuff` works though.

Comment: @fluteflute and OP: In order to get **bold** and *italics*, use double- and single- asterisks around the phrase instead of tags. A triple asterisk will give you ***bold and italicised*** (this works in questions, answers, and comments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design, probably to encourage people to have the content in questions and answers and not comments.

Reference: [Allow HTML tags in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference. I still wish that the markup (markdown?) was consistent between questions and comments. OTOH, maybe it is. I'll see if the *markdown* stuff works next time I post a question.

Comment: When leaving a comment I usually ask myself in the head "if it takes more than a few characters I should be updating my answers anyway"